# Saving new record in Ember-cli using POST mehod is not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, hapi.js

I am using ember-cli with ember-data 1.8.1.I have write api in hapijs.
Problem is when i am creating a new record and saving it.then it should be POST request,but it sending method 'OPTIONS', and saying 404 not found.
I find error in console is :-

```
[Report Only] Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3000/users' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729"

OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

**SO Here is the code which i write for saving record**

```
var onSuccess = function(post) {
              console.log(post);
            };
var onFail = function(post) {
              console.log("fail");
              console.log(post);
            };    
var user = store.createRecord('user', {
            email : "Email",
            phone : "phone",
            password : 'password',
            "isd_code_id" : 1,
            slug: "puneet"
          });

 user.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
```

It always goes in fail, I already add cors in hapijs, GET request is working fine.Only problem is saving record.
Please Help what should i do for make it work

Comment: Which version of hapi? How did you enable CORS?

Comment: Problem is with hapiJs.I am using hapi-8.0.0.It is not working with it,but when downgraded to hap-6.4.0, its working.Can you tell how to make it work with hapi-8.0.0.

Comment: I have added cors object in config and then in every route i am included this cors object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS configuration has changed in hapi 8.0, so maybe you are using the old configuration. This is how you can enable CORS in hapi 8.0:

```
var server = new Hapi.Server({
    connections: {
        routes: {
            cors: true
        }
    }
});
```